# Search not working for more than two words in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Recently, I migrate MySQL database to ElasticSearch.
and its basically dump of million resumes.

Now, I am using official PHPClient API to interact with ElasticSearch.

FYI,
below is my cluster index fields

```
[name, email, state, resume_text, visa]
```

I have few questions. I tried searching online resources to tweak my search.
But could not meet with my requirement.

Below is the issues, I am head on wall to it.

### Issue 1 :

tried to search

> "content management system"

with field resume_text 
could get the desired result, the search result is worst, sometimes cant even find

> "content"

,

> "management"

or

> "system

" 
few resumes.

So, with less than two words, its returns bad result set.

Below is the syntax, i got from documentation and other resources

```
$searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array('match' => array('resume_text' => $skill_name));
```

I tried even term, but not good result.
I dont know, what I did wrong.

### Issue 2 :

I need to get the resumes, with respect to location i.e. `"state"`.
I tried to search with one less state, it doesn't give proper results. I get other states resumes too.

only one state works perfect.
Alabama and Alaska, it should get me only these two results

```
$searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['should'][]['term'] = array('cur_state' => $state_name);
```

### Issue 3 : [ Not an issue, a doubt ]

Can we search results from field to a variable.
For example.

```
$visa_variable = "Citizen, Green Card, H1B";
```

now, how can we search relating to 3 words in variable without spliting or explode in php then
searching independently .

Hmm. thats it. thanks

Comment: Is the field resume_text analyzed?

Comment: @isaac.hazan It's already analyzed as `text` by defualt